# How can I allow Chrome to access iCloud folders

Tags: icloud, google-chrome

I can access `file:///Users/falk/` just fine, but not `file:///Users/falk/Documents/` or `file:///Users/falk/Desktop`. The "loading" indicator just spins and spins. Those folders are under iCloud.

Is there a setting I need to change?

This only happens on one of three Macs I have access to.

Comment: Sounds like Chrome needs permission to access Documents and Desktop folders. Normally, you should get a dialog asking you to allow. Check the System Preference Security panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can changed Chrome’s permissions in **System Preferences→Security & Privacy→Privacy→Files and Folders**.

Comment: Hmm, good idea, but I just checked and Chrome has access to both Documents and Desktop. I wonder if I just need to reboot.

Comment: When I rebooted, I got a popup asking if I wanted to give Chrome access, and then everything was fine.